# HighCharts – Horizontal chart: moving bars down, make space for labels above them

Tags: javascript, highcharts

With the horizontal bar chart, I want the X-Axis labels to appear above each bar. Having crosshair enabled, I want both bar and label to be vertically centered within the area of the crosshair.

I've already changed the positioning of labels by modifying text alignment and x, y coordinates. I can imagine that the simplest solution would be to offset y position of the bar, but I'm not sure whether it's possible.

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
          x : 0,
          y : -24,
          align: 'left'
        },
        crosshair: {
          width: 60,
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
          snap: true,
        },
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pointPlacement` property to reposition the columns:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPlacement: -0.1,
        ...
    }
},
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1anzyLhf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use pointPadding option from plotOptions

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
         stacking: 'normal'
        },
      bar: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
      }
    }
```

working code sample for reference

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QeKWqG

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
          x : 0,
          y : -24,
          align: 'left'
        },
        crosshair: {
          width: 60,
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
          snap: true,
        },
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
         stacking: 'normal'
        },
      bar: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
      }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Increasing padding can help sometimes, but what I’m looking for is to do it „unevenly”, so eg. to have more padding on the top, and less padding on the bottom.

Comment: But it maybe something else. Anything that will make the bar go lower, to make more space for the label above.